# Is there the ability to start/stop a project timer through the API?

Tags: xero-api

I've been looking through the API reference, and I can't tell if there's a way to start and stop a timer. In the Projects -> Time section of the docs, this doesn't seem to be listed, but I'm hoping that I'm missing something.

(For context, I've been using Clockify to track my time, using a StreamDeck plugin. I'd like to have the same StreamDeck functionality to control Xero timers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently supported. Please feel free to add your idea to the Xero Uservoice forum https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-accounting-api

Comment: Thanks - will add that.
For now I'll most likely stick with Clockify for time tracking and use the webhooks when a time log is finished to push that into Xero